# c++ auto with overriding signed/unsigned

Tags: c++, c++11, types, armadillo

In the following code:

```
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    mat A;
    auto x=A.n_rows-5;
    ....
```

`x` is `long long unsigned int` and I want it to be  `long long int`. How can I fix this problem?

It should be noticed that on different versions of this library, different types have been used, so I cannot mention `long long int` directly and I need to use `auto`.

Comment: The short answer is to convert `A.n_rows` to be `long long int` before doing the subtraction.   Bear in mind that the behaviour will be undefined if `A.n_rows` is a value that cannot be represented in a `long long int` (there are values a `long long unsigned` can represent that a `long long int` cannot), so you will need to deal with that.   You also haven't explained why you want `x` to be signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the C++11 type traits library to get a [signed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_signed) or [unsigned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned) version of a numeric type.

To get an unsigned int:

```
std::make_unsigned<int>::type
```

So to get a signed version of `A.n_rows`, try:

```
std::make_signed<decltype(A.n_rows)>::type x = A.n_rows - 5;
```

For any other qualifiers, there are corresponding templates to convert between types:

- reference types - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref
- pointer types - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer
- etc. (add or remove const, or volatile qualifiers)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are already using armadillo, I think the best (or easiest) way would be using `arma::sword`.

```
sword x = A.n_rows - 5; // This can also compile without C++11.
```

It will solve the problem of "different versions of this library, different types have been used", since `A.n_rows` has the type `arma::uword`, which is unsigned version of `arma::sword`.  See, http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#uword

Comment: using a more explicit declaration might make the intent clearer: `auto x = sword(A.n_rows) - 5;`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
auto x=A.n_rows-5;
```

To

```
long long int x = (long long int)(A.n_rows - 5);
```

In order to cast away the unsigned.

Comment: You can keep `auto` when you cast: `auto x = (long long int)(A.n_rows - 5);`

Comment: That conversion will give undefined behaviour if `A.n_rows - 5` results in a value that a `long long int` cannot represent.

Comment: Are you joking? did you read my post about why I do need to use `auto`?