# How to cast an arbitrary std::integral type to unsigned?

Tags: c++, unsigned, c++-concepts

I am trying to cast an std::integral type to unsigned when a special flag is set i.e. it should simply be interpreted as an unsigned number in this case. This cast is necessary in that case, because the number needs to be passed as an unsigned to another function not controlled by me later on. However, I can't find a solution that compiles successfully.

Here's a MWE with the most promising solution (which I took from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049554):

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

bool change = true;

void do_something(const std::floating_point auto num) {
    // Do something else
    std::cout << "Got floating num: " << num;
    return;
}

void do_something(const std::integral auto num) {
    if (change) {
        // Interpret as unsigned
        std::make_unsigned<decltype(num)>::type unsigned_num = num; // FAILS
        std::cout << "Got integral and changed to unsigned: " << unsigned_num;
    } else {
        // Do something else
        std::cout << "Got integral and keeping as is: " << num;
        return;
    }
}

int main() {
    do_something(1);
    do_something(-1);
    do_something(0.5);

    change = false;
    do_something(1);
    do_something(-1);
    do_something(0.5);
}
```

(compile with g++ --std=c++20)

Compiler Error Message:

```
mwe.cc:7:30: error: ‘floating_point’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘is_floating_point’?
    7 | void do_something(const std::floating_point auto num) {
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              is_floating_point
mwe.cc:7:45: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘auto’
    7 | void do_something(const std::floating_point auto num) {
      |                                             ^~~~
mwe.cc: In function ‘void do_something(int)’:
mwe.cc:9:46: error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘enum’?
    9 |         std::cout << "Got floating num: " << num;
      |                                              ^~~
      |                                              enum
mwe.cc: At global scope:
mwe.cc:13:30: error: ‘integral’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘internal’?
   13 | void do_something(const std::integral auto num) {
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
      |                              internal
mwe.cc:13:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘auto’
   13 | void do_something(const std::integral auto num) {
      |                                       ^~~~
mwe.cc:13:6: error: redefinition of ‘void do_something(int)’
   13 | void do_something(const std::integral auto num) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
mwe.cc:7:6: note: ‘void do_something(int)’ previously defined here
    7 | void do_something(const std::floating_point auto num) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
mwe.cc: In function ‘void do_something(int)’:
mwe.cc:16:45: error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘enum’?
   16 |                 std::make_unsigned<decltype(num)>::type unsigned_num = num;
      |                                             ^~~
      |                                             enum
mwe.cc:16:49: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   16 |                 std::make_unsigned<decltype(num)>::type unsigned_num = num;
      |                                                 ^
mwe.cc:16:57: error: expected initializer before ‘unsigned_num’
   16 |                 std::make_unsigned<decltype(num)>::type unsigned_num = num;
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
mwe.cc:17:74: error: ‘unsigned_num’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘unsigned’?
   17 |                 std::cout << "Got integral and changed to unsigned: " << unsigned_num;
      |                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                          unsigned
mwe.cc:20:68: error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘enum’?
   20 |                 std::cout << "Got integral and keeping as is: " << num;
      |                                                                    ^~~
      |                                                                    enum
```

What is causing these issues and how would you suggest to overcome them?

Comment: please include compiler error message in the question

Comment: your are only missing a `typename` https://godbolt.org/z/98T3n8cY7

Comment: or use `std::make_signed_t`. In general you should prefer such helper type aliases over the bare `type` member alias, because of just this very issue you encountered

Comment: ... and you need to ask your compiler to compile as c++20

Comment: what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: You also have to consider what happens when you convert negative numbers to unsigned, and if that *really* is what the called function expects.

Comment: Are bound to use `std::integral`? Why not use the more specific `std::unsigned_integral`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should do as in the example here:
[make_unsigned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned)

That is, for your example:

```
using unsigned_num_t = std::make_unsigned_t<decltype(num)>;
const unsigned_num_t unsigned_num = num;
```

Or as you were told, you should only add **typename**, like this:

```
typename std::make_unsigned<decltype(num)>::type unsigned_num = num;
```